# Does firstOrCreate respects casts?

Tags: laravel

I have a tag model with the following:

```php
$table->string('name')->unique();
$table->string('slug')->unique();
```

I am using `firstOrCreate()`:

```php
$name = "test tag 1";
Tag::firstOrCreate(['name' => $name, 'slug' => $name])
```

An inbound cast is handling the slug before inserting it. This works fine for the first time only. It seems like it only uses the cast for inserting, not for checking if it exists.

Inserting:

```sql
insert into
  "tags" ("name", "slug", "updated_at", "created_at")
values
  (
    'test tag 1',
    'test-tag-1',
  )
```

Checking:

```sql
select
  *
from
  "tags"
where
  (
    "name" = 'test tag 1'
    and "slug" = 'test tag 1'
  )
```

Is there something I could so it would also use the cast when checking with the `firstOrCreate()` method?

Comment: You checked existing of 'test tag 1' in both columns, and because of dashes in slug, firstOrCreate just create it again and again. It is better to use it like `firstOrCreate(['name' => $name],['slug' => $slug]);`

Comment: Casts apply on model instances so with no instance there's no cast. It's a bit of a conundrum.

Comment: This is useful too: https://www.archybold.com/blog/post/laravel-eloquent-firstorcreate-casts-model-attribute

Comment: @iazaran Thanks, moving the slug to a second argument solved my problem didn't think about using that. I guess for this particular case, it's enough. With other, more complicated casts, it won't be much help.

Comment: Great! Yes it should work with casts, somehow. Laravel needs to take a look at this case.

Comment: what 'cast', you mean a mutator?